# Rails, how to add a bootstrap-theme via bower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a bootstrap-theme for my rails project, for example a theme from bootswatch: http://bootswatch.com/superhero/

Currently, bootstrap is integrated in my project via Bower:

Bowerfile:

```
asset 'bootstrap-sass-official'
```

Application.css

```
 *= require 'bootstrap-sass-official'
```

The [Documentation on Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/help/) says that to use a bootstrap theme, is to download the theme and to replace it with the existing bootstrap-file. Since I used bower to get bootstrap, there is no file to replace with.

What do I need to do, to use the Bootstrap-Theme?

EDIT:

I added superhero.css to stylesheets and added it to application.css:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require 'bootstrap-sass-official'
 *= require 'superhero'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme is having customised bootstrap then you can use bower. You need to download the bootstrap file from your theme and put in `app/assests/stylesheets`
and then call it in `application.css`

```
*= require 'bootstrap'
```

Comment: I added the bootstrap file to stylesheets and added it to application.css. But it seems not to be working. Any further advices? (See my edit)

Comment: Nevermind, I should have removed bootstrap-sass-official. Thanks